# Preparedstatement date check is null

Tags: java, postgresql, date, jdbc

I need to make query like this

```
SELECT * FROM tanks WHERE (creationDate >= ? or ? is null) and (creationDate >= ? or ? is null)
```

Then I've set

```
stmt.setObject(1, fromDate);
stmt.setObject(2, fromDate);
stmt.setObject(3, toDate);
stmt.setObject(4, toDate);
```

but I can't execute a query cause I've got an exception that Java cannot determine type of parameter $2 (sorry, I don't know why but all exception are in Russian).

When I get rid of **? is null** everything works fine.

Does anybody have ideas how to deal with it?

Comment: what do you mean by "all exception are in Russian"?

Comment: Not sure about postgresql, but in some database servers you can cast the parameter to an explicit type (eg `CAST(? AS DATE) IS NULL`)

Comment: @Alexey `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: не удалось определить тип данных параметра $4`

Comment: What happens when you replace `.setObject` with `.setDate`?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

`SELECT * FROM tanks WHERE (creationDate >= ? or creationDate is null) and (creationDate >= ? or creationDate is null)`

And you should only set two parameters corresponding to two ?

Not sure of anything that will allow you to use "? is Null" but you can do it in an alternative way something like this:

```
 if(fromDate!=null && toDate!=null){
      statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tanks WHERE creationDate >= ? and creationDate >= ?");
      statement.setDate(1,fromDate);
      statement.setDate(2,toDate);

      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
 } else if(fromDate==null && toDate==null) {
      statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tanks");
      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
 } else {
      statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tanks WHERE creationDate >= ? ");
      statement.setDate(1,fromDate!=null?fromDate:toDate);

      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it is not. This query make me able to pass some parameters as optional.

Comment: Do you want to work with fromDate and toDate with null values?

Comment: Yes, it will make me able to pass it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Regression-Problems-with-Timestamp-arguments-td5770255.html), it seems this is a PostgreSQL JDBC driver bug that was introduced with protocol version 3.

The workarounds suggested in the thred are to degrade the protocol

```
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?protocolVersion=2
```

or to explicitly cast the arguments

```
SELECT ?::timestamp IS NULL
SELECT CAST(? AS timestamp) IS NULL
```

I was experiencing this same problem and was able to resolve it using the explicit cast.